# Angular 4 Child View not updating

Tags: angular

My structure is the following:

**parent.component.html**

```
<listing-categories #listingCategories [categories]="listingsPaths"></listing-categories>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
this.listingsPaths = [];
for (let category of listing.categories) {
    // Subscribing to a service and pushing the data to an listingPaths
    this._projectService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
     this.listingsPaths.push(data);
    });
}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Input() public categories;
```

**child.component.html**

  **...**

As you can see I want to send the listingPaths array which is populated in promise, and I want to render it in a child component. I've tried using **OnChanges** on child component but there weren't any changes triggered when I would push a new object to an array.

I managed to do a 'work around' by creating an Observable and emitting the newly added item to a Child component. How ever I would like to send an array as a whole to a Child component, not emit item by an item.

Here is the solution with Observable:

**parent.component.ts**

```
_listingPaths = new Subject<any>();
_listingPathsChanges$ = this._listingPaths.asObservable();
```

And in for loop, instead of pushing the item to an array, I am emitting it to the child component as:

```
this._listingsPaths.next(data);
```

**child.component.ts**

```
 this.categories.subscribe((data) => {
     this._categories.push(data); // I don't want this part, I want to receive whole array from a parent
     this.cd.markForCheck();
 })
```

Comment: Have you set the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your child copmonent?? If yes, then you may need to remove it. Any change in the array is not a change in object reference and hence it wont trigger a change detection cycle.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create an observable and send the data to child using the async pipe `(observable$ | async)`.

Comment: Yes I did. It’s a bit weird that this would be the solution. How would the one deal with it then if you need to listen for changes both for object and array? I will try to do it tomorrow, thanks!

Comment: Read my second comment. Use observables. If you are updating the object manually, use `obj = Object.assign({},obj)` to create a new instance of the object and trigger the change detection.

Comment: Removing ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush worked.  I'm really curious why this was the cause, going to research it a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please mark it as an answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in your child component?? If yes, then you may need to remove it. Any change in the array is not a change in object reference and hence it wont trigger a change detection cycle.

Alternatively, you can create an observable and send the data to child using the async pipe `(observable$ | async)`.

Comment: This solution worked like magic after trying `onChanges`, `*ngIf` and what not. Thanks a lot @Sachin